# Spring batch partition few steps running for long time

Tags: spring-batch, spring-batch-admin

I am using spring batch for Reading Oracle DB(~2million records) and writing to Files.

The below code uses partition concept with grid-size=8. Two jobs(Job1, Job2) uses the same code to excecute. Each job process ~1million data.

Each job has grid-size=8 * 2 jobs= 16 threads running in parallel.
1 or 2 threads are taking very long time to complete. Bcz of 1or2 threads total excecution time is very long.

Below is code snippet. Appreciate your suggestions.

```
<bean id="dataSource" class="com.aap.batch.common.DataSourceJdbc"><!--Connection details -->
<bean id="jDBCTemplate" class="org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
</bean>

<bean id="taskExecutor" class="org.springframework.core.task.SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor" />

<step id="masterStep" >
        <partition step="slave" partitioner="rangePartitioner" >
            <handler grid-size="8" task-executor="taskExecutor" />
        </partition>            
</step>

<step id="slave" xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/batch">
    <tasklet>
        <chunk reader="fetchReader" writer="flatFileWriter" processor="dataProcessor" commit-interval="100" />
    </tasklet>
</step>

<bean name="rangePartitioner" id="rangePartitioner" class="com.aap.batch.RangePartitioner" scope="step" >
    <property name="jDBCTemplate" ref="jDBCTemplate" />
</bean>

<bean name="fetchReader" id="fetchReader" class="com.aap.batch.FetchReader" scope="step" >
    <property name="jDBCTemplate" ref="jDBCTemplate" />
</bean>
```

Comment: Have you done any profiling?  What's the bottle neck?

Comment: Hi Michael, few threds are hung to exceute the method having queries. Do i need set pool-size or concurrencyLimit or something else?

Comment: So after a while some threads just hung while the others continue to execute? Job finishes successfully after that(all items finished)?

Comment: yeah. 1 or 2 threads hung while other continue, after completing other these hung threads also complete. Finally job finished. But taking long time to finish, due to hung threads.

Comment: Not able to get the root cause, Any thoughts plz?

Comment: I would appreciate if someone can have solution...